# UWP cannot get correct virtual key state after switching back from the other app

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a login dialog that I would like to display message to the user when the Caps Lock is on. I add the following code to check current key state of VirtualKey.CapitalLock to determine if the message should be displayed or not when the PasswordBox has focus.

```
private bool IsCapsLockOn() {
    // check caps lock key state
    var keystate = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.CapitalLock);
    return (keystate & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Locked) != 0 ;
}
```

This function works fine, but CoreWindow.GetKeyState will not be able to get the correct locked state with the following steps:

1. Enable Caps Lock to On state
2. IsCapsLockOn() returns true
3. Switch focus to different app or Desktop
4. Switch back to my app and the CapsLock key remains locked, then the IsCapsLockOn always returns false and the keystate is CoreVirtualKeyStates.None.
5. Unlock CapsLock and lock it again will resolve the issue to receive the correct state.

I also tested on checking both key states of CapitalLock and NumberKeyLock, and both of key states won't be able to retrieve after step #4 when both of them are locked. The issue will be gone after either one of the key is unlocked and locked again.

Is this behavior a bug in UWP? Or is there any other system call required to reset the state?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked GetKeyAsync? They work in quite different ways, meybe it will help. (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041130-00/?p=37173)

Comment: @Mailosz thanks for sharing the link; however, the post was in 2004 not for UWP.

I have also tried GetAsyncKeyState, but the correct state key could be retrieved only the first call unless there is any change on the same key state.

Comment: Hmm, I did a quick test in my project, and I don't see this bug. I open my app, press capslock, switch to desktop, switch back to my app and the state is still reported as Locked.

Comment: It looks like the issue is in PasswordBox. I have tried to Window.Current.Activated event and it is able to get the correct key state. The GotFocus event handle in PasswordBox may not be able to get the latest key state after switching back to my app.

I have also tried the same GotFocus in TextBox and PasswordBox in Windows App UI Basic sample, and the issue can be reproduced in both TextBox and PasswordBox elements.